# Find where DNS is being overridden on Windows 11

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

When trying to connect to plane WiFi, I was unable to resolve the captive portal. When looking at my network settings, I saw that at sometime I had my DNS set to override as 8.8.8.8. (I vaguely recall doing this on some wifi connection with unreliable DNS.) `NSLookup` confirms that 8.8.8.8 is being used, and Get-DnsClientServerAddresses lists 8.8.8.8 as the ServerAddress for Wi-Fi.

Unfortunately, I can't find where that override is set. I checked the `Network Connections > Properties > IPv4`, and it's set to use automatic. I checked for a hosts file in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` and I don't see any reference to 8.8.8.8.

Is there a good way to see where else in my system the value could be coming from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look here.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces{*interface-UUID*}\ProfileNameServer

We had a similar issue where phantom DNS previously set kept coming back, I am not exactly sure the root cause, only that I have seen it on more than one system in the last year.

Comment: This worked (changing the value in the registry directly)! Do you know how to map the interface-UUID to where it's set within the interface?

Comment: Not following you, as in how to tell which interface the UUID belongs to?

Comment: Just in case, t can be found under the Device Class ID 4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318 (Network Adapters)

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Comment: yep, thank you!